# Django: information leakage problem when using @login_required and setting LOGIN_URL

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-urls

I found a form of information leakage when using the @login_required decorator and setting the LOGIN_URL variable.

I have a site that requires a mandatory login for all content. The problem is that you get redirected to the login page with the next variable set when it's a existing page.

So when not logged in and asking for:

```
 http://localhost:8000/validurl/
```

You see this:

```
 http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/validurl/
```

And when requesting an non existing page:

```
 http://localhost:8000/faultyurl/
```

You see this:

```
 http://localhost:8000/login/
```

Which reveals some information that I dont want. I thought of overriding the login method, forcing the next to empty and calling 'super' on this subclassed method.

An additional problem is that some of my tests fail without the LOGIN_URL set. they  redirect to '/accounts/login/' instead of '/login/'. Hence why I'd like to use the LOGIN_URL but disable the 'auto next' feature.

Anybody that can shed some light on the subject?

Thanx a lot.

Gerard.

Comment: IMO, that's semi-correct behaviour. You should really return 404 for non-existing resources, and 403 for existing resources which require authorisation to view. In other words, you shouldn't be directing to the login page for things that don't exist - show a very bare 404 page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include this line as the last pattern in your `urls.py` file. It will re-route urls that do not match any other pattern to the login page.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    ...

    (r'^(?P<path>.+)$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {
        'url': '/login/?next=/%(path)s', 
        'permanent': False
    }),
)
```

EDIT: To keep raising 404 pages to authenticated users, do the following:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
def fake_redirect(request, path):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404()
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next=/%s' % path)

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    ...

    (r'^(?P<path>.+)$', fake_redirect),
)
```

Comment: jbochi, interesting solution. However, this kills the normal 404 behavior for people that are properly logged in. I have to check how far my custom 404 handler is of influence. It checks if somebody is logged in, then decides 404 or login. I see a loop emerging there :)

Comment: @GerardJP. You're right! I have edit my answer. Please see the second solution. If you want, you can modify the line `raise Http404()` to call your custom 404 handler.

Comment: jbochi, great! That is indeed the one I was looking for. For the time being I chose to loosen my test a bit, and disable LOGIN_URL, since it's handled by my 404 handler. Otherwise I'm only implementing some code for a variable I don't use, besides the fact that it breaks my test. But I definitely will remember that 'catch all' url trick. Thanx again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Remember you can set the answer as accepted if you liked it.